# Harvard style bbx, cbx, and lbx

Tags: biblatex, harvard-style

I am trying to get a Harvard style bibliography with Biblatex. Not just something that looks more or less like Harvard style, but the actual Harvard bibliography. APA generates:

`last name, initials first name. (year).`

while Harvard style is:

`last name, initials first name, year.`

I think this is the most important difference between APA and Harvard style bibliographies. I have seen many questions and styles that more or less resemble Harvard style bibliographies, but none of them are really it. I have an APA bbx, cbx and lbx (Dutch), and I'm looking for either an Harvard bbx, cbx and lbx or a way to modify the APA files so that they generate a real Harvard style bibliography.

Comment: 'Harvard' style is a generic term for author-date bibliographies: you'll find a lot of people using 'Harvard' to mean whatever the style they use is!

Comment: I don't think there is actually an official Harvard Style Guide ([Anglia Ruskin](http://libweb.anglia.ac.uk/referencing/harvard.htm) has a nice guide, so do other universities) like APA Style or the Chicago Manual of Style. So the best you can do is finding a style that comes closets to what you want (maybe APA or standard `authoryear`) and modify it to your needs.

Comment: The LaTeX package called `harvard` comes with no less than seven [!] different bibliography style files. As @JosephWright has remarked, there simply is no single "harvard" bibliography and/or citation style. Nowadays, "harvard style" simply seems to be a generic term for "author-year citation style".

Comment: I didn't realise it was just a generic term. He just mentioned that in this particular class, Harvard referencing is mandatory and gave us a link to the Anglia Rushkin pdf guide; not sure whether that means I have to use the Anglia Rushkin style in particular or just any Harvard style, but it's probably better to be safe than sorry. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you like what `biblatex-apa` does and just want to change

> last name, initials first name. (year).

to

> last name, initials first name, year.

add the following lines to your preamble.

```
\newbibmacro*{labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {\iffieldundef{origyear}
      {}
      {\setunit{\addcomma\space}\printfield[noformat]{origyear}}}%
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}\printdateextralabel}}
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\newbibmacro*{labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {\iffieldundef{origyear}
      {}
      {\setunit{\addcomma\space}\printfield[noformat]{origyear}}}%
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}\printdateextralabel}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{aksin,wilde,murray}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields
[image]